# Read already existing Atlas with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, image, sprite-kit

I want to load an image **atlas** I have **already stored** in my computer as a single image into an application. All of the tutorials I have found so far use the creating folder with the .atlas extension. I already have an image atlas. Do I have to break it up into smaller images or is it possible to use it as it is?

This is the image I am referring to:
[image: This is only for educational purposes, the images are from an old computer game called "Neverwinter Nights" by Bioware]

Just to make it clear, I am **not building a game.**

**Edit**

So, what I want basically is to pick one of the squares inside of the atlas image, and use it to create an image that would appear inside the clear view you see in the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I need more context,  are you asking if you can make a preloaded atlas package to be able to distribute to others?  You not wanting to build a game is what throws it off.

Comment: BTW, .atlas folder is the old way and I recommend not using it anymore.  The preferred way is do do it through the XCAssets folder, because it contains metadata for the graphics in the atlas.

Comment: I don't want to make a preloaded assets package, I want to know if there is some way to tell ios that this image is my atlas and to use it. I want to use all those small images but that means I would have to edit them one at a time and I really don't feel like it.

Comment: Also, you said me not wanting to make a game is what is throwing it off. Do you mean that sprite kit can only be used in game applications?

Comment: I am trying to understand your purpose so I can provide a proper answer

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully this answers your doubts

Comment: OK, I'll write up the answer tonight

Comment: So... any luck?